# How to link to link table in lyx

Tags: lyx

I have edited a few tables in an lyx file A. And now I am creating a beamer presentation based on that file. Is there a easy way to use the tables created in file A in the presentation. The presentation is also edited in lyx.

Comment: There are many options to reuse contents, but it is unclear what are you searching  ... An `article` to `beamer` conversion?  Use the `clipboard` package?  How copy & paste in LyX? How use children documents (See Menu Insert > File >  ...)? To reuse tables could be a good idea copy source LaTeX code of each table in independent `.tex` files and insert ERT boxes with `\input{fileA}` `\input{fileB}` etc. in the main Beamer document (of course, taking care that the preamble  have the packages needed for children files (i.e, may be none, may be  `booktabs` plus  `tabularx`, etc, etc. ).

Comment: Note that in LyX you do not need ERT for `\input`. You can go to Insert > File > Child Document